# CSS issue with height and width of image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have image on jsx/html page that is div:

```
 <div className="card-row-image" style={getBackgroundImage(thumbnail)} />
```

Problem is cus in css class `height` and `width` are `68px` but when I open application, on page width is lower then `68px`

You can check the screenshot:
[image: ss]

Css part of code:

```
.card-row-image {
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Why with of image is not 68px?

Comment: Whats the CSS for the wrapping list element? Is it a flex?

Comment: Try min-width and min-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline style provided in `getBackgroundImage(thumbnail)` has a higher priority than the CSS rules linked to the class. You have a couple of options:

1. Change `getBackgroundImage` to allow specifying another size (not 'thumb')
2. Apply the inline style, but remove the width and height from it:

```
const { width, height, ...styleWithoutSize } = getBackgroundImage(thumbnail)
<div className="card-row-image" style={styleWithoutSize} />
```

3. Change the order of priority with `!important`

```css
.card-row-image {
  height: 68px !important;
  width: 68px !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah you should avoid this, which is why it's the 3rd option, the last resort. It's better to make sure you don't provide a bad inline style in the first place